# how to copy list from one sitecollection to another sitecollection

Tags: list, development, powershell, custom-list, list-template

What is the best way to automate to copy a list from one site collection to another. We don't want to create a list template manually and moved to another site collection and all that process.

we need something to automate. may be using powershell. but trying to know what is the best way to do it.

Comment: what is sharepoint version?

Comment: It's SharePoint 2013

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the SharePoint designer and create a workflow to copy the lists item from source to destination.

[Copy item from one list to another, using Sharepoint designer workflow](http://www.fivenumber.com/copy-item-from-one-list-to-another-using-sharepoint-designer-workflow/) and also check [this link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/2e965512-9d1d-40ac-9370-31e289401479/update-an-item-in-another-list-with-a-workflow-in-sharepoint-2010)

you can try 3rd part tool [Copy a List Item To Another Site Collection (and Other Workflow Conductor 1.5 Cross-Site Collection Features)](http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/bambooteamblog/archive/2010/10/07/copy-a-list-item-to-another-site-collection.aspx)

You can try the below powershell script to copy a list to different site collection.

```
Function CopyList([string]$SourceWebURL, [string]$TargetWebURL, [string]$ListName, [string]$BackupPath)
 {
    #Get the Source List
 $SourceList =(Get-SPWeb $SourceWebURL).Lists[$ListName]

    #Export the List from Source web
    Export-SPweb $SourceWebURL -ItemUrl $SourceList.DefaultViewUrl -IncludeUserSecurity -IncludeVersions All -path ($BackupPath + $ListName + ".cmp") -nologfile

   #Import the List to Target Web
    import-spweb $TargetWebURL -IncludeUserSecurity -path ($BackupPath + $ListName + ".cmp") -nologfile
 }
#Call the function
CopyList "http://sharepoint.crescent.com" "http://sharepoint.crescent.com/teams/marketing" "Banner" "C:\Temp\"
```

Read more: http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2012/12/copy-list-between-sites-powershell.html#ixzz3cUGkZB8l

Comment: Yeah but here you are manually creating the destination list in another site collection and just copying list items. My Requirement is "I have an existing list in one site collection and I have automate everything to copy entire list with the content to another site collection.

Comment: check my updated answer.

Comment: if it works then please mark it as anwser so others get benefit and i get some rewards.